# Finding the MLE of an expected value of a function with random variable X

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution

> Let $X_1, X_2, …, X_n$ be a random sample of a random variable X, which has Gamma
>   distribution with parameters $α = 3$ and $β$.
>
> a) Find maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of $β$.
>
> b) The weekly downtime X (in hours) for a certain industrial machine has Gamma
>   distribution with parameters $α = 3$ and $β$. The loss, in dollars, to the industrial operation as a result of this downtime is given by $L = 30X + 2X^2$. Find MLE of expected loss.

I found the answer for part a to be $β=\frac{\bar{x}}{3}$ and it seems right since the expected value for gamma distribution is $E[X] = αβ$.

But I am not sure how to deal with part b. Only thing I can think of is finding $E[L]=E[X^2+30X]$, taking the derivative of $ln(E[L])$ with respect to $β$ and setting it to $0$. This gives me an estimator for $β$, but as I understand the question, I need to find an estimator for expected loss. Can you help me?

Comment: You want to estimate $E[L] = E[30X+2X^2] = 30\alpha\beta + 2\alpha(1+\alpha)\beta^2 = 90\beta + 24\beta^2$. For this, use your answer from part a along with the invariance property of maximum likelihood estimators.

Comment: Is $α(1+α)β$ the value of $E[X^2]$? And if so, do we obtain it from the formula $Var(X) = E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$?

Comment: Yes, $E(X^2) = \alpha(1+\alpha)\beta^2$. (I had a typo in my comment at first). We have $(E[X])^2 = \alpha^2\beta^2$ and $Var(X) = \alpha\beta^2$, so $E[X^2] = Var(X) + (E[X])^2 = \alpha\beta^2 + \alpha^2\beta^2 = \alpha(1+\alpha)\beta^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I should be able to take it from here.

Comment: @averagemonkey Comments are not for providing answers.  If you wish to answer the question, you should post an answer instead.